# QGIS legend feature count by map extents

Tags: qgis, legend, layouts, feature-count

I have a legend in a layout and want to show the feature count within the extents of the map on the layout (Map 1). When I click on 'Show feature count for each class of vector layer', the count of all features in the the entire map show up in brackets. I have tried to limit the features to *map_extent* through the *aggregate* function in the expression editor without success.

Here is what I tried.
layer: 'Edificios Culturales',
aggregate: 'count',
field name: 'tipo',

```
aggregate( 'Edificios Culturales','count','tipo',intersects($geometry,map_get(item_variables('Map1'),'map_extent')))
```

[image]

Comment: Field names need to be in double quotation marks --> try `"tipo"`.

Comment: What works so far is `aggregate('Edificios Culturales','count','tipo',"tipo"='centro' OR "tipo"='biblioteca')` which gives me the correct number of features of the entire map. I cannot get the `intersects(geometry1, geometry2)` to work.

Comment: I just found a post which makes this work inside of a label. [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321578/showing-feature-count-for-layout-extent-on-legend-using-qgis). The question that remains is if there is a way to loop over all categories. Here is the working version `aggregate('Edificios Culturales','count','tipo',"tipo"='biblioteca' AND intersects($geometry,map_get(item_variables('map1'),'map_extent')))`

Comment: make sure to set the same CRS for the layer and the project!